# how can I make my bot disconnect from voice after 15 seconds being idle in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a music bot, that disconnects after being idle for 15 seconds.

My code:

```js
            player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
                message.channel.send('<:Bye:958269757541466145> **Queue finished... Leaving!**')
                connection.disconnect();
            });
```

I am using Discord.js v13.8.0 and Node.js 16

Comment: setTimeout(() => { //code }, 15000); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout function -

```
  player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      message.channel.send('<:Bye:958269757541466145> **Queue finished... Leaving!**')
      connection.disconnect();
    }, 15000);
  })
```